# How to add Dependent request filter as load test plugin in VSTS?

Tags: performance, load-testing, vsts

**Tool:** VSTS

I have around 10 web-tests under a single load test. I have written web-test plug-in that will remove **404 Not found** errors for dependent requests (such as gif files). I have added the web-test plugin for all the 10 web tests.

Now, I have to add another 30 web test to the same load test. Is there a way to add a load-test plug-in that would do the same task of web-test plug-in by removing the 404 not found errors from the individual responses? Or should I add the web test plugin for all the remaining 30 web test individually?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

**You probably need to stick to the web-test plugin**

The web-test plugin is presumably operating on the post request event args, which is not available to load test plugins - the closest you would get is the TestFinished event. The standard arguments for this event do give access to the test results, but I don't think they are editable.

References:

- Web Test Plugin - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243191.aspx
- Load Test Plugin - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153.aspx